# How to define a Monad instance "m a" with "a" in Typeclass Show?

Tags: haskell, monads

I would like to define a monad instance with the container M as monad and with the contained type `a` which should be a member of class `Show`. This constraint (that `a` is member of `Show`) should be ensured by the type system.

I gave it a try like this, but `M` is unfortunately not of the right Kind:

```
data M = forall a. Show a => M a 

instance Monad M where
 return x = M x
```

All other attempts to achieve that, run into the following problem: Since `Monad` is a constructor class, I don't have explicit access to the type `a` of the contained element(s), so I can't restrict it.

Does anyone know a solution to this without defining a new `Monad` class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it is actually possible to restrict the parameters of a type constructor in some sense, using GADTs:

```
data M a where
    M :: (Show a) => a -> M a
```

Unfortunately this doesn't actually help you here. In a way it actually makes things worse, because rather than having a `Monad` instance without the constraint, it becomes impossible to write the instance at all.

If you look at the above constructor type signature, it clearly resembles `return`--which demonstrates why what you're doing is fundamentally impossible. The type for return is: `(Monad m) => a -> m a`, and as always unbound type variables are implicitly universally quantified at the outermost level, so you can read that as "for all possible types `a`, and all possible types `m` which are instances of `Monad`, given a value of type `a` you can construct a value of type `m a`". The "for all" phrasing is quite literal there--the type of return isn't just using a type variable, it's actively asserting that any type `a` whatsoever must be allowed.

So, in short, no. There's no way to do what you want because the standard `Monad` class *explicitly specifies* the opposite.

Answer (score 5):

You may not be able to do exactly what you're asking, but another possibility is for your particular monad to provide an action that explicitly does whatever you're thinking of doing with `Show`. That is, supposing you have:

```
data M a = {- ... -}
instance Monad M where -- notice: no Show constraint
    {- ... -}
```

Then you could additionally supply some action:

```
report :: Show a => M a -> M a
```

I can't think off the top of my head of a good use of this pattern with `Show`, but I do know of a similar example where you might wish for an `Ord` constraint. The setup is that you'd like to make a monad that's nondeterministic (like `[a]`), but doesn't have duplicates (like `Set a`). Removing duplicates requires some context like `Eq` or `Ord`, but we can't demand that on every `return`/`>>=` operation. So instead we demand that the user explicitly mark the points where duplicates should be coalesced:

```
newtype Setlike a = Setlike { toList :: [a] }
instance Monad Setlike where
    return x = Setlike [x]
    Setlike xs >>= f = [y | x <- xs, let Setlike ys = f x, y <- ys]

collapse :: Ord a => Setlike a -> Setlike a
collapse = Setlike . Data.Set.toList . Data.Set.fromList . toList
```

This can be used like so:

```
valuesOfInterest = collapse $ do
    v1 <- allValues
    v2 <- allValues
    doSomethingInteresting v1 v2
```

Then, even if some pairing of `v1` and `v2` happen to result in the same value of interest, that value will only appear once in the result.

Some similar trick is likely possible for your use case as well.

Answer (score 2):

No. This is not possible, although it is easy to explain. Have a look at the type signature of `return`:

```
return :: Monad m => a -> m a
```

The signature can't change, so your monad must accept any content types. Since the type class itself does not mention the content type, there is no way to enforce constraints on it.

One thing you could do is writing this constraint on all functions that need it and dropping the global restriction. The soundness of the system is still guaranteed, if you can can proof the existance of a `Show` constraint only when it is needed.

Comment: `Kind mis-match: The first argument of 'Monad' should have kind '* -> *',  but 'M a' has kind '*'`

Comment: @camccann Sorry. No I understand the question. See my updated answer, which is similar to yours.

Comment: Perhaps someone took issue with your final paragraph? It's correct in some sense, but also misses the point in some ways: e.g., you can't enforce any constraint on using the `Monad` in `Applicative` style, and it wouldn't help if the monad itself needs the `Show` constraint, e.g., an auto-logging writer monad that uses `show` to log the value `(>>=)` is applied to.

Comment: @camcann What I meant is, that if the variable needs to be in show, one can manually hint that via the type system of the appropriate function (like in `f :: Show a => a -> M a`). In case of `Writer`, one has an additional parameter to the type (The instance of `Monad` is for `Writer t` and not for `Writer`) that can carry the show context for the value to log.

Comment: Right, but the former only applies to functions that introduce new monadic values, applied with `(>>=)`. Anything that can be done using just `(<*>)` can't be limited that way. And my point in the latter was a situation where the definition of `(>>=)` would need the `Show` context on the type parameter. Perhaps imagine a `Monad` instance for `Data.Set.Set` instead, the same issue arises.

Comment: @camccann Ah, now I see your point. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with some extreme trickery.  See the [rmonad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rmonad) package for an implementation.  However, it's probably not worth it.

Why do you need to have the constraint that `a` is `Show`able?  It would be easier to just enforce the Show constraint at that point, then it'll naturally propagate where necessary.

Comment: The question did specify "without defining a new `Monad` class". There're varying degrees of trickery possible to get various approximations, but none that can be wrapped around the standard `Monad`s. Though `RMonad` probably comes closest in making the fewest concessions possible for its `AsMonad` wrapper.

Comment: @camccann: `AsMonad` is usable with the standard `Monad` class.

Comment: Yes, but doing so (obviously) ignores the restrictions from `RMonad`; using `AsMonad` alone doesn't give you anything you can't do directly with a plain `Monad` instance. The utility of it is that the wrapping/unwrapping stores extra info and thus lets you preserve as much of the `RMonad`'s properties as possible when round-tripping through functions using regular `Monad`s.